# cuales son los frameworks-dependencias en spring

Tags: java, spring

> cual es la dependencia de @services
>
> cual es la dependencia de @repositorios
>
> cual es la dependencia de @controllers

me refiero a dependencias en el archivo pom.xml

si no me equivoco @controllers tiene la dependencia

> starter.web

y cuales son las dependecias para repositorios y servicion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de la dependencia `spring-boot-starter-web` está la dependencia `spring-context` la cual contiene a `@Service, @Repository, @Controller` entre otras.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Este es el árbol de dependencias:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y que es core? al momento de crear un projecto nuevo hay la opcion de marcar core, ui y web

Comment: Los módulos `spring-core` y `spring-beans` proporcionan las partes fundamentales del framework, incluyendo las características IoC (Inversión de control) y también la Inyección de Dependencias, aquí puedes encontrar información mas detallada:
[spring-core](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) y 
[spring-web](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-web)

Answer (score 0):

Siendo más preciso, @Controller corresponde a Spring MVC, y marca un Controlador que puede ser "escaneado" para responder ante peticiones que puedes nombrar con la anotación @RequestMapping.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, si te refieres a @Service @Controller y @Repository corresponden a spring-context.

Si ejecutas el comando mvn dependency:tree podrás ver qué artefacto está incorporando spring-context, así como la versión.